# One screen after another in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am tackling this [Constructing a web based tool using Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563201/constructing-a-web-based-tool-using-matlab#comment16923662_12563201) project.

In this regard, I need my GUI to seemlessly go from one screen to another, for example the welcome screen to a screen containing the MENU. I can call one fig from another but that will pop up another window. i need it to be in a single window. The background image in each screen will remail the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the widgets you need and play with their 'visible' property:

```
>> a = uicontrol('Style','edit','String','hello','visible', 'off');
>> set(a, 'visible', 'on')
```

You can also group them into uipanels

```
hp = uipanel('Title','Main Panel','FontSize',12,...
            'BackgroundColor','white',...
            'Position',[.25 .1 .67 .67], 'visible', 'off');
a = uicontrol('Style','edit','String','hello','parent', hp);
set(hp, 'visible', 'on')
```

Comment: Thanks for the above answer. Though this works perfectly it get a bit complicated while developing specially using GUIDE if you have to add a lot of screens. Is there another way to do this. Thanks again

Comment: @Juggler You could create figures using GUIDE and create it with visibility off, like `fig =   figure(..., 'Visible', 'off'). Then when you want to switch views, hide the first window, and after that show the other one. Other than that I have no ideas.